# Systemd-homed on Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm

Tags: systemd, pi-5

I recently bought a Raspberry Pi 5 and installed the latest version of Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm. My question is related to systemd-homed. When I create a new user following the instructions on https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd-homed, I cannot login. That is, when I try to use login, it seems to do nothing, but checking the logs it logins and logouts immediately. Moreover, when I use su, it returns an error saying the user does not exist.

I do not know if anybody has tried this before.

P.S.: Following the same steps in my Ubuntu 23.10, everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got it working. In case somebody is interested, I needed to also install the package libnss-systemd, and modify /etc/nsswitch.conf to add systemd to passwd, group, shadow, and gshadow.

[*] https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/nss-systemd.8.html